# Flutter - Handle page-specific REST API Query Parameters

Tags: flutter

I have an issue to pass multiple query params with page in url in Flutter

```
BASE_URL/products?page=1&brands[]=1&categories[]=1&tags[]=1&min_price=0&max_price=100
```

with page number = 1
and api query params  `brands[]=1&categories[]=1&tags[]=1&min_price=0&max_price=100`

So How to Handle pagination with this query params.

I'm using this package => https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_paginator_ns
but not work with multiple query params because it take int as page number only.